# Can someone explain the types of acceleration data (RAW, BODY, GROUND)? And how they differ from each other?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am working with a research group and we are using acceleration to determine variables necessary for our work. But I am confused at the advatages and disadvanteages of each type of acceleration data. Under [Enumeration Documentation](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-api-reference/namespaceDJI_1_1OSDK_1_1Telemetry.html#a563d2333dc43253129a3915970f99cfaa99df11872b1818d274fb5d068abe07fd) I found three different types of acceleration data: RAW, GROUND, and BODY. I understand the different frames of reference for GROUND and BODY, but I am puzzled as to what RAW means. Can anyone give me an explanation of differences between these, and explain to me what acceleration raw is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated (08/15/2018) Telemetry API Reference includes information about frames of reference for each topic and also warns if there are non-standard frames involved. You can submit any issues you have with the docs on the [documentation Github repo](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Onboard-SDK-Doc).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot. Would it be feasible to have some sort of link to the documentation when looking at the API? Being for elements of the API that are explained further in the documentation (this instance for example), so their location in the API reference would have a link to more information in the documentation. :) [EDIT] It's awesome that the DJI engineers are so active on stack overflow. Very uncommon in my experience with other companies.